# How to trigger event in one ComboBox when value selected in another ComboBox?

Tags: vba, events, combobox

I have a ComboBox "select the view" which contains (WEEK, MONTH, QUARTER and ALL). I would like when the first ComboBox is selected for example : "WEEK", the second ComboBox "select the period" will be populated without a click button with "W1,W2,....W52" or if we select "QUARTER" will be populated with "Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4" etc.

[image: Form View]

I tried the code below but it didn't work quite well.

```
Private Sub ComboBox4_Change()

Dim index As Integer

With Sheets("SUMMARY")
index = .ComboBox3.ListIndex
    .ComboBox4.Clear

    With .ComboBox4
        Select Case index
            Case Is = 0
                .AddItem "W1"
                .AddItem "W2"
                .AddItem "W3"
                .AddItem "W4"
                .AddItem "W5"
                .AddItem "W6"
                .AddItem "W7"
                .AddItem "W8"
                .AddItem "W9"
                .AddItem "W10"
                .AddItem "W11"
                .AddItem "W12"
                .AddItem "W13"
                .AddItem "W14"
                .AddItem "W15"
                .AddItem "W16"
                .AddItem "W17"
                .AddItem "W18"
                .AddItem "W19"
                .AddItem "W20"
                .AddItem "W21"
                .AddItem "W22"
                .AddItem "W23"
                .AddItem "W24"
                .AddItem "W25"
                .AddItem "W26"
                .AddItem "W27"
                .AddItem "W28"
                .AddItem "W29"
                .AddItem "W30"
                .AddItem "W31"
                .AddItem "W32"
                .AddItem "W33"
                .AddItem "W34"
                .AddItem "W35"
                .AddItem "W36"
                .AddItem "W37"
                .AddItem "W38"
                .AddItem "W39"
                .AddItem "W40"
                .AddItem "W41"
                .AddItem "W42"
                .AddItem "W43"
                .AddItem "W44"
                .AddItem "W45"
                .AddItem "W46"
                .AddItem "W47"
                .AddItem "W48"
                .AddItem "W49"
                .AddItem "W50"
                .AddItem "W51"
                .AddItem "W52"

            Case Is = 1
                .AddItem "JANUARY"
                .AddItem "FEBRUARY"
                .AddItem "MARCH"
                .AddItem "APRIL"
                .AddItem "MAY"
                .AddItem "JUNE"
                .AddItem "JULY"
                .AddItem "AUGUST"
                .AddItem "SEPTEMBER"
                .AddItem "OCTOBER"
                .AddItem "NOVEMBER"
                .AddItem "DECEMBER"

            Case Is = 2
                .AddItem "Q1"
                .AddItem "Q2"
                .AddItem "Q3"
                .AddItem "Q4"
            Case Is = 3
                .AddItem "ALL"
        End Select
    End With

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the issue you're having?

Comment: When I select a value in ComboBox 1, I want ComboBox 2 to be populated dynamically (No click used) @Brian M Stafford

Comment: Try putting your code into `ComboBox3_Change`.

Comment: I did what u said, and it works @Brian M Stafford

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd break it up into two functions, easier to maintain.
2. you can use arrays to make code smaller
3. My code assumes ComboBox3 contains the filter and combo4 is what needs to be populated. I think you may have mixed those two up above.

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()

    with thisworkbook.worksheets("Summary")
        call PopulateCombo4(.ComboBox3.value)
    end with

end sub
```

```
Private Sub PopulateCombo4(val as string)

    thisworkbook.worksheets("Summary").combobox4.clear

    dim arr() as string
    if val = "QUARTERLY" then
        arr = split("Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4")
    Elseif val = "WEEKLY" then
        '....[same as above with W1,W2....]
    end if            

    dim s as string
    for each s in arr
        thisworkbook.worksheets("Summary").combobox4.additem s
    next

end sub
```

Let me know if you have any follow up Qs. going to meeting.

Comment: Don't you think that call looks ugly? Especially on Subs. Just use`PopulateCombo4 .ComboBox3.value`.Force OP to use some naming pattern except the auto-generated e.g. `ComboView`, `ComboPeriod`,`ComboYear`.Use `Select Case`if you have to tell appart several conditions on a value, and I would build the combo itemd by a for ... loop (and`MonthName(n,False)`). You know [RubberduckVBA](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/)? That will suggest other optimizations too (and the other features and the [blog](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/07/08/about-class-modules/))